# To break line in my tooltip

Tags: html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and here I am fetching record in my tooltip. But problem is that, if I want multiple name in my tooltip, it doesn't go to new line as I have tried so many times like, `&#013;`, `<br>`, or something like javascript. But nothing is working. 
I want suggestion for that.
Here is my code:

```
<td><a href="#" class="my_tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo nl2br("$row->active_subject; \n$row->active_note"); ?>"><?php echo $row->active_subject; ?></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this where ever you want to break line `&#013;`

Comment: `<td><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $row->active_subject;?>&#013;<?php echo $row->active_note; ?>"><?php echo $row->active_subject; ?></a></td>`

I used like this, but didn't work....

Answer (score 0):

You can use white-space:pre-wrap on the tooltip. This will make the tooltip respect new lines. Lines will still wrap if they are longer than the default max-width of the container.

```
.my_tooltip {

        white-space:pre-wrap;
    }
```

If you want to prevent text from wrapping, do the following instead.

```
.my_tooltip {
    white-space:pre;
    max-width:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td><a href="#" class="my_tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo nl2br('$row->active_subject; \n$row->active_note'); ?>"><?php echo $row->active_subject; ?></a></td>
```

Remove " " with ' ' in title.

Comment: Its not working as it can not fetch my record from an array.

Comment: then remove quotes both ' and  " just write title="<?php echo nl2br($row->active_subject; \n$row->active_note); ?>"